# Firebase Realtime Database: failed to order data by timestamp

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database list contains more than 10,000 records, each record has `Email` and `Date` keys, and `Date` is a timestamp.

Ordering data using `orderByChild` retrieving data unorderly. code snippet:

```js
firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('Date').once('value').then((d)=>{
  let users = d.val();
  Object.keys(users).map( 
    k => console.log( new Date(users[k].Date) )
  );
});
```

**Records:**

```json
{
  "users" : {
    "-MNfAJqQps-t3tPexBXD" : {
      "Date" : 1587827466215
    },
    "-MNfAO1PbkcLOqjjrk2o" : {
      "Date" : 1593781601194
    },
    "-MNfAcnfCZ7bpEGO9lMX" : {
      "Date" : 1588037833767
    },
    "-MNfAcnfCZ7bpEGO9lMY" : {
      "Date" : 1590966701420
    },
    "-MNfAcngMq0yQfq-zJD7" : {
      "Date" : 1574637809000
    },
    "-MNfAcngMq0yQfq-zJD8" : {
      "Date" : 1565127290858
    },
    "-MNfAcnhU0gK2PfDRYdU" : {
      "Date" : 1566914768371
    },
    "-MNfAcnhU0gK2PfDRYdV" : {
      "Date" : 1580480141148
    },
    "-MNfAcnirZFlPnikmjA9" : {
      "Date" : 1604432784043
    },
    "-MNfAcnirZFlPnikmjAA" : {
      "Date" : 1563010563269
    }
  }
}
```

**Rules:**

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "false",
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "Date"
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
4/25/2020, 5:11:06 PM
7/3/2020, 3:06:41 PM
4/28/2020, 3:37:13 AM
6/1/2020, 1:11:41 AM
11/25/2019, 1:23:29 AM
8/6/2019, 11:34:50 PM
8/27/2019, 4:06:08 PM
1/31/2020, 4:15:41 PM
11/3/2020, 9:46:24 PM
7/13/2019, 11:36:03 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you call d.val(), the order of the child nodes is lost.
So you should loop `d` by using `forEach` before `d.val()`.

```
firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('Date').once('value', d=> {
  d.forEach(child => {
    const child_data = child.val();
    const date = child_data.Date;
    console.log(new Date(date));
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your check. If you mind please upvote too. thanks. I will help you more if you have any question related to firebase